# Update LayoutParams in Animate end Xamarin Android

Tags: android, animation, xamarin.android, android-animation

I have a FrameLayout and I'm animating it in Xamarin Android with Animate API. The problem is that when the animation ends, LayoutParameters of the view is not updated. I know that is a regular behavior of Android animation and I need to set the LayoutParameters when Animation ends. But when I set it, The view disappears.

This is my code:

```
var targetX = somevalue;
var currentX = someothervalue;
Result.Animate().
     SetDuration(300).
     TranslationXBy(targetX - currentX).
     WithLayer().
     WithEndAction(new Java.Lang.Runnable(() =>
     {
         (Result.LayoutParameters as FrameLayout.LayoutParams).LeftMargin = targetX;
         Result.RequestLayout();
     })).
     Start();
```

Comment: The first thing what comes in my mind is that maybe you have to use context.RunOnUiThread.. Check your logs if there's  some exception.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I've tried it before. no change.